# How to match hex char in String using re module

Tags: python

I have input styring like `cat\x00\x01\x01` and I want to match hex char using re module. I try do something like this:

```
import re

string='cat\x00\x01\x01'
match=re.findall('\\x0[0-9]',string)
print match
```

But it works wrong. How to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that string there isn't actually a backslash, an `x` and digits after that. There are the characters with ASCII codes `00` and `01`.

You can match [those (unprintable) characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) between ASCII `00` and ASCII `1F` (plus ASCII `7F`) with the regex

```
match = re.findall('[\x00-\x1F\x7F]', string)
```